# What happened to Batman in the Arrowverse?

Tags: dc, batman, arrowverse, batwoman-2019

The premise of the *Batwoman* show in the Arrowverse is that Gotham City has gone into chaos since the disappearance of Batman a few years prior to the first episode. Kate Kane, Bruce's cousin, takes over the mantle of Batman and tries to restore peace in the city.

**What happened to Bruce Wayne/Batman in the Arrowverse?**

From a quick search, it seems that he disappeared after killing the Joker. But what happened to him after? Is he alive?

The show is over, and the Arrowverse is down to a final season of *the Flash*, so we may not have any more information. Any word of God about the whereabouts of Batman would the show not have been canceled? Was he supposed to reappear in Gotham?

Comment: https://youtu.be/5GDvVplPEqo?t=35 Edit: Posted this as a joke because I find the context funnily similar